# Babel Watcher won't run in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, babeljs

I don't know where to start. I have configured my File Watcher in WebStorm many different ways but can't get it to do anything. I don't even see a console to give me feedback.

I can run babel from the terminal so it is installed. I am pointing the program to /usr/local/bin/babel in OS X.

What switch am I missing to get WebStorm to actually run Babel?

Answer (score 0):

I had my settings in the Watcher for JavaScript and not JSXHarmony.